# Have you been on aeroplane/bus/bicycle?

Tags: grammar

When we asked whether he or she has been ride any vehicle.

How do we say it?

> "**Have you been on aeroplane/bus/bicycle?**"

Comment: How about "have you been on any vehicle?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask:

> Have you ever been on a plane *or* an aeroplane (*BrE*) *or* an airplane (*AmE*)?
>
> Have you ever been on a bus?
>
> Have you ever been on a bicycle *or* a bike? *or* Have you ever ridden a bicycle?

(Note: In BrE the verb "ride" refers only to things that can be straddled, such as horses and bikes.  In AmE the verb has been extended so that you can "ride" any vehicle.)

If you want to ask about *any* vehicle, you could try asking:

> Have you ever been on any vehicle?
>
> Have you ever travelled on a vehicle of any kind?